# Can we define this keyword as a reference variable in Java?

Tags: java

```
public class Temp {
  private int x = 3;

  public void show() {
    this.x = 4;
    this.show(); // same as show();
  }
}
```

Can we say that `this` is a reference variable ?

Comment: calling `this.show()` from `show` will produce an infinite recursion leading to StackOverflowError.

Comment: You cannot call it a _variable_ because the value cannot change.

Comment: just google **What is this in java**

Comment: Reference? Yes.  Variable? No.  So, "reference variable"? No.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3):

> [...] the keyword this denotes a value that is a reference to the object for which the instance method or default method was invoked [...]

So `this` is not a reference variable, it is in fact a keyword. From the above description you *could* say it behaves *like* a reference variable (or better said a constant since you can't change it) if it is used in a certain context.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a reference indeed, however it is a constant, thus you can't change its value. `this` always references an object that object method was invoked on.

Comment: Can someone call it a reference variable ??

Comment: @AbhishekDubey Only a guy called Michał Tomaszewski from PJATK college. ; p But it is a definitely a reference just a constant one. I believe( didn't check it ) that it is implemented as local constant in scope of method as it would be the most natural way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. it is in fact a reference variable which refers to the current object.

Comment: It is not a _variable_!